# Extbase—get all items within a given category

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am quite new to Typo3 and Extbase so I am really kind of lost right now… We have a category tree like that:

```
+ root
++ chairs
 ++ wooden chairs
  + plastic chairs (2)
  + generic chairs (0)
  + broken chairs
  ++ slightly broken chairs (3)
   + heavily broken chairs (1)
   + chairs that kill (10)
```

And we have a dataset (custom extension and database table etc.) and each record can be assigned to a category, what is a built in functionality of typo3. We also have a Repository class which implements a `findByCategory()` method.

We would like to list **all** records from the custom table, which are member of a given category. So in case of the example above, `findByCategory('broken chairs')` should yield 14 items and `findByCategory('chairs')` 16.

Is there any Helper/Utility Class we can use to obtain all categories from a given parent category?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to extend the CategoryRepository and implement your own method. The method could look like this :

```
    /**
     * Finds categories based on their parents, possibly taking categories2skip into account
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     * @param array $categories2skip
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function findByParent($parent, $categories2skip = array()) {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $constraints = array();
        $constraints[] = $query->equals('parent', $parent);
        if (count($categories2skip) > 0) {
            $constraints[] = $query->logicalNot($query->in('uid', $categories2skip));
        }
        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd($constraints)
        );
        $result = $query->execute();
        return $result;
    }
```